# Is there a web app like goodreads.com, but for movies or music instead of books?

Tags: webapp-rec

I keep lists of movies/books/music to watch/read/listen to. Recently the lists have been growing too large/complicated to keep as part of my normal to do list. I've moved my reading list to `goodreads.com`.

Is there a similar site for movies or music?

At the very least, it should be able to keep track of:

- Movies/music I need to watch/listen to
- Movies/music I have watched/listened to
- Details about each movie/album I add to my collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of http://GetGlue.com, which does this and more for movies, music, books, wine, "topics" and more.

Answer (score 1):

I did some preliminary research and came up with the following list:

- icheckmovies.com
- fffilm.com
- narvoo.com
- lunch.com
- flixster.com
- flickchart.com
- filmfresh.com
- filmcrave.com
- criticker.com
- imdb.com
- nanocrowd.com
- themovietracker.com

None of these satisfied me.

Spurred by this, a couple of friends and I have developed [SeenTh.at](http://seenth.at)

Our plan is to blend a very unique user interface with the simple task of cataloging movies you have seen. If you want to rate, review, recommend, add a movie to a must see list, you'll be able to do that too.

Comment: for anyone that's interested, we've posted some pre-release pics of seenth.at over on dribbble.com (http://dribbble.com/ShaneHelm/projects/6...). i would be interested to hear any comments or feedback you might have. again, we'll be opening up our private beta sometime this fall. get on the list by signing up at http://seenth.at.

Comment: another quick update...seenth.at is super close to launching. obviously, we've missed the desired fall launch, but we're still hard at work.  update at the blog (http://seenth.at/blog).

Answer (score 0):

For movies, you might want to look at [MovieLens](http://movielens.org/) even though it's oriented towards suggesting movies you might like.  You can use the "wishlist" flag to track movies you want to see, and rate movies you have seen to track them, possibly using tags.  It doesn't seem to have provision for personal (private) comments, though.

Answer (score 0):

For managing the movies I own or want to see, I use [DVD Aficionado](http://www.dvdaf.com/).

There are also lots of sites with large movie databases, but for that you can't beat IMDB itself. (It has an owned list, a wish list, and just about every movie ever made, but it doesn't have anything for music or books.)

Since you specifically asked for one site to handle all three though, my second suggestion would be [GuruLib](http://www.gurulib.com/). Although a bit more rough around the edges, it functions quite good using what seems to be the Amazon Product database for item search. (However, I'm skeptical of any site which doesn't make it clear how to export your collection, so proceed with caution. I had a tough time finding a site which does all types of content and also supports exporting to other formats/platforms.)

Lastly, worthy of mention is [Delicious Library](http://www.delicious-monster.com/), a tool which you can use to quickly scan barcodes on backs of DVDs, music albums and books to create your digital library. I have not used it personally, but have heard good things.

Answer (score 0):

- **Music**: [Last.fm](http://last.fm). It can track what you are listening too (on PC, Mac and smartphones) and then recommend you music based on your tastes. Plus it can recommend events (concerts, festivals). Oh yes, and it's a web radio too :) And yes, it has information about artists and albums. Alternative to Last.fm is Pandora.
- **Movies and TV**: GetGlue (mentioned before, the biggest TV/movie check-in service) or [Miso](http://gomiso.com/). Allows you to keep track of what you have seen on TV or in the movies. These however don't do recommendations yet. And I have not seen a service that would do tracking and recommendations based on what's been tracked. Only one or the other.

**Bonus**: [TouchGraph Amazon Browser](http://www.touchgraph.com/amazon) allows you to explore networks of Movies, Books and Music based on matching genres, persons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## [Poppley](http://poppley.com/)

Poppley is a website that matches the kind of thing you have mentioned. You can find new movies, discover what your friends have enjoyed and rate and review the movies you have seen. [**Disclaimer:** I helped to build Poppley and am a big fan of several of the sites in this genre!]

If you get a chance to give Poppley a try, then feel free to add feedback in the form on the site. I will make sure I reply to all feedback received!

## [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/)

There are ways of logging in and rating and reviewing sites on IMDb too.

## [iCheckMovies](http://www.icheckmovies.com/)

Is a social website based around movies and has a wide range of titles to choose from.

## [Flixster](http://www.flixster.com/)

Flixster are the guys behind the great movies iPhone app and have bought the movie site rotten tomatoes.

Comment: Is there a way to login to Poppley without using Facebook? This is a deal-breaker for me.